# Accessing attributes of a datatype

Tags: haskell

I created a new datatype:

```
data Human = Human [Names] Age
  deriving(Eq,Show)
type Names = String
type Age = Int
```

And now I want to access the elements of [Names] for an object of type Human:

```
human1 = Human ["FirstName","LastName"] 22
```

Is there a simple way to do this for my example such as `Names human1` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either make your own accessors

```
names :: Human -> [Names]
names (Human n _) = n
```

or use lenses, which gives you that and much more.
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-tutorial-1.0.3/docs/Control-Lens-Tutorial.html

Answer (score 5):

In this case the simplest way is to define a function, which pattern-matches the `Human` data type:

```
getNames (Human names _) = names
```

Otherwise, you can use Record Syntax to define fields of the record:

```
data Human = Human { names :: [Names], age :: Age }
```

Using this syntax you achieve `names` and `age` functions, which allow you to access the fields:

```
human1 = Human ["FirstName","LastName"] 22
names human1
```